# How to make output of a select list be dependant on parent list?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two arrays that have a parent category and sub category each appear in a select list, how do I make the sub category show items only from its parent category?

```
 <?php $carMakes = array(
 'show_option_all'    => '',
 'show_option_none'   => ('All Makes'),
 'orderby'            => 'ID', 
 'order'              => 'ASC',
 'show_count'         => 0,
 'hide_empty'         => 1, 
 'child_of'           => 25,
 'exclude'            => 0,
 'echo'               => 1,
 'selected'           => 0,
 'hierarchical'       => 0, 
 'name'               => 'cat',
 'id'                 => '',
 'class'              => 'postform',
 'depth'              => 0,
 'tab_index'          => 0,
 'taxonomy'           => 'category',
 'hide_if_empty'      => false
); ?>

<?php $carModels = array(
 'name'               => 'subcat',
 'hierarchical'       => 1,
 'parent'             => get_cat_id('model'),
 'show_option_none'   => ('All Models'),
 'hide_empty'   => 0  ); 
?>

<?php wp_dropdown_categories($carMakes); ?> 

<?php wp_dropdown_categories($carModels); ?>
```

need to only show car models that belong to car makes for example

```
Make=Toyota  Model=Supra
             Model=Corolla
             Model=Tundra
```

Here is an example of the category structure

```
Make (parent category)
     -Toyota
     -Nissan
     -Mazda
     -Ford

    Model (parent category)
     -Supra
     -Skyline
     -Mustang
     -Rx7
     -Corolla
```

Comment: If possible would like to do it without the use of JS

Comment: Then you'd need a couple of requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always wanted to do an exercise on chained selections using Ajax, so, here we go ;)

This is a full plugin and should be installed in `wp-content/plugins/your-plugin-name` folder. Consists of three files, the plugin itself, the Javascript file and the Ajax loader image.

Install the plugin and activate, and **insert the following in some theme template file**:

```
<?php 
if( class_exists( 'BRSFL_Chained_Selection' ) ) {
    // Parameters: ( $cat_id, $dropdown_text )
    BRSFL_Chained_Selection::print_cats( 1, 'All Makes' ); 
}
?>
```

Also, adjust the two calls to `wp_dropdown_categories` as desired. Check the code comments for details.

The sub-categories dropdown is **modified in response to changes in the categories dropdown:**

> [image]

### chained-categories.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Chained Categories
 * Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15748968/1287812
 * Description: Demonstration of chained categories with Ajax. 
 *   Plugin structure based on <a href="https://gist.github.com/3804204">Plugin Class Demo</a>, by Thomas Scholz.
 *   Use the dropdowns in the theme with this PHP method call: BRSFL_Chained_Selection::print_cats();
 * Author: Rodolfo Buaiz
 * Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
 */

add_action(
    'plugins_loaded',
    array ( BRSFL_Chained_Selection::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
);

class BRSFL_Chained_Selection
{
    /**
     * Plugin instance.
     *
     * @see get_instance()
     * @type object
     */
    protected static $instance = NULL;

    /**
     * URL to this plugin's directory.
     *
     * @type string
     */
    public $plugin_url = '';

    /**
     * Path to this plugin's directory.
     *
     * @type string
     */
    public $plugin_path = '';

    /**
     * Access this plugin’s working instance
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @since   2012.09.13
     * @return  object of this class
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Used for regular plugin work.
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @since   2012.09.10
     * @return  void
     */
    public function plugin_setup()
    {    
        $this->plugin_url    = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
        $this->plugin_path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        $this->load_language( 'chainedselections' );

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'script_enqueuer' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_query', array( $this, 'custom_query' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_query', array( $this, 'custom_query' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Constructor. Intentionally left empty and public.
     *
     * @see plugin_setup()
     * @since 2012.09.12
     */
    public function __construct() {}    

    /**
     * Enqueue frontend scripts
     */
    public function script_enqueuer() 
    {
        wp_register_script( 
             'ajax-quote' 
            , plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/ajax.js'
            , array( 'jquery' ) 
        );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-quote' );

        wp_localize_script( 
             'ajax-quote' 
            , 'wp_ajax' 
            , array( 
                 'ajaxurl'  => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) 
                , 'ajaxnonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_chained_selection_validate' )
                , 'icon' => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/ajax-loader.gif' 
            ) 
        );
    }    

    /**
     * Ajax create sub-categories dropdown
     */
    public function custom_query()
    {
        // Security
        check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_chained_selection_validate', 'security' );

        // Check if jQuery posted the data
        if( !isset( $_POST[ 'chained_subcat_id' ] ) )
            return false;

        // Adjust parameters
        $carMakes = array(
            'show_option_all'    => '',
            'show_option_none'   => 'All ' . $_POST[ 'chained_subcat_name' ],
            'orderby'            => 'ID', 
            'order'              => 'ASC',
            'show_count'         => 0,
            'hide_empty'         => 0, 
            'exclude'            => 0,
            'echo'               => 1,
            'selected'           => 0,
            'child_of'           => $_POST[ 'chained_subcat_id' ],
            'hierarchical'       => 1, 
            'name'               => 'chained-subcontainer',
            'id'                 => '',
            'class'              => 'postform',
            'depth'              => 1,
            'tab_index'          => 0,
            'taxonomy'           => 'category',
            'hide_if_empty'      => false
        ); 

        // Print sub-categories
        wp_dropdown_categories( $carMakes );
        exit();
    }       

    /**
     * Loads translation file.
     *
     * Accessible to other classes to load different language files (admin and
     * front-end for example).
     *
     * @wp-hook init
     * @param   string $domain
     * @since   2012.09.11
     * @return  void
     */
    public function load_language( $domain )
    {
        $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', get_locale(), $domain );

        // Load translation from wp-content/languages if exist
        load_textdomain(
                $domain, WP_LANG_DIR . $domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo'
        );

        // Load regular plugin translation
        load_plugin_textdomain(
            $domain,
            FALSE,
            $this->plugin_path . '/languages'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Print the dropdown in the frontend
     */
    public static function print_cats( $cat_id, $dropdown_text )
    {
        // Adjust parameters
        $carMakes = array(
            'show_option_all'    => '',
            'show_option_none'   => $dropdown_text,
            'orderby'            => 'ID', 
            'order'              => 'ASC',
            'show_count'         => 0,
            'hide_empty'         => 0, 
            'exclude'            => 0,
            'echo'               => 1,
            'selected'           => 0,
            'child_of'           => $cat_id,
            'hierarchical'       => 1, 
            'name'               => 'chained-categories',
            'id'                 => '',
            'class'              => 'postform',
            'depth'              => 1,
            'tab_index'          => 0,
            'taxonomy'           => 'category',
            'hide_if_empty'      => false
        ); 

        // Print categories
        wp_dropdown_categories( $carMakes );

        // Empty dropdown for sub-categories
        echo '<div id="chained-subcontainer">
                <select name="chained-subcategories" id="chained-subcategories">
                    <option value="">- Select a category first -</option>
                </select>
            </div>';
    }
}
```

### ajax.js

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) 
{ 
     var data = {
         action: 'custom_query',
         security: wp_ajax.ajaxnonce
     };

    $( "#chained-categories" ).on( "change", function( e ) 
    {
        // Add specific data to the variable, used to query the sub-categories
        data[ 'chained_subcat_id' ] = $( this ).val();
        data[ 'chained_subcat_name' ] = $(
            '#chained-categories option[value=' 
            + $( this ).val() 
            + ']'
            ).text();

        // A sub-category was selected
        if( $( this ).val() > 0 )
        {
            // Ajax loader icon 
            $( '#chained-subcontainer' ).html( '<img src="' + wp_ajax.icon + '">' );

            // Ajax call
            $.post( 
                wp_ajax.ajaxurl, 
                data,   
                // No error checking is being done with the response                
                function( response )
                {
                    $( '#chained-subcontainer' ).html( response );
                }
            );
        }
        // No selection, show default
        else
        {
            $( '#chained-subcontainer' ).html( '<select name="chained-subcategories" id="chained-subcategories"><option value="">- Select a category first -</option></select>' );
        }           
    });
} );
```

### ajax-loader.gif

[image: ajax loader]

Comment: How can this be edited so that it limited to Category 'Make' and sub Category for 'Make' which is 'Model'? at the moment it goes and grabs every category in wordpress

Comment: I changed the  $carMakes array 'child_of'  to the parent category 'make' but doesnt render the sub categories of 'models' any ideas?

Comment: How can I use the results from these drop downs in a search field?
I tried adding getting into <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/"> but url isn't  being recognized   mysite.com/?chained-categories=182&chained-subcontainer=183&my_search=c_search

Comment: I cant get it work with the categories I have, it still has the same issue as mentioned earlier I changed the $carMakes array 'child_of' to the parent category 'make' but doesnt render the sub categories of 'models'

Comment: Answer updated. Now, you feed the category ID and the Dropdown "option none" text when calling the plugin in the theme template. PS: I've cleaned previous comments to not clutter the thread.

Comment: This discussion lead me do to more research and I found a plugin with a bit more features http://www.peterjharrison.me/2011/11/category-ajax-chain-select-wordpress-plugin-2/ thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Why not use objects?
You need a factory to make cars.

a great reference: http://sourcemaking.com/creational_patterns

I also like to think about keep objects small, simple, and to do as little as possible.  Break functions down to simple concepts like "make" and "show". That makes them interchangable and extensible. You will eventually be able to just ask for $this->model->

I would approach like this:

1 object to organize the data //model

another to build your rows//controller

another to display //view

To start looking at it like that, write some functions first to gain an understanding of what you are wanting to know.

```
foreach (make)->show(models);
```

You may discover you need to query the data differently... In other words, ask the db a more specific question up front rather than filter it after you've received it.  Maybe filtering now seems quicker, but how many other questions and filtering will you have to do later?

One more comment: php is more controllerish and javascript feels more viewish.  I say solve the problems in their most appropriate and simplest context- stick with php on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this without AJAX is to get a list of all your "Make" categories, then generate a dropdown for each "Model" of each "Make" using wp_dropdown_categories() with the child_of parameter. Hide all the "Make" dropdowns upon page load, attach a change event handler to the "Make" dropdown and when it's called, show the appropriate "Model" dropdown while hiding all the rest. The showing/hiding can be done with jQuery or pure JS. Each "Model" dropdown will have to have a unique ID that can be used to identify which "Make" it belongs to.

Comment: That's certainly not the *only* way.