# How to put AJAX response in select tag?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Here is my HTML

```
<select class="expand" id="search_category" style="display: none;">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
 <option value="Arts & Music">Arts & Music</option>
 <option value="Academic & Tech">Academic & Tech</option>
 <option value="Odd Jobs">Odd Jobs</option>
 </select>
```

When I selects any option, on change jQuery AJAX is called. Here is JSON response

```
["Lacrosse","Squash","Basketball","Swimming","Golf","Tennis","Football","Other","Baseball"]
```

I also tried to get HTML response like this way

```
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Lacrosse">Lacrosse</option>
<option value="Squash">Squash</option>
<option value="Basketball">Basketball</option>
<option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
<option value="Golf">Golf</option>
<option value="Tennis">Tennis</option>
<option value="Football">Football</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
<option value="Baseball">Baseball</option>
```

But failed to put either of these two responses into below HTML select tags.

```
<select id="showSubCats"></select>
```

jQuery is running correctly. I can alert these values. How to put these values into select tags like?

```
<select id="showSubCats">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Lacrosse">Lacrosse</option>
<option value="Squash">Squash</option>
<option value="Basketball">Basketball</option>
<option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
<option value="Golf">Golf</option>
<option value="Tennis">Tennis</option>
<option value="Football">Football</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
<option value="Baseball">Baseball</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#search_subcategory').css('display','none');
    jQuery('#search_category_loader').css('display','none');
    jQuery('#search_category').on('change',function(){
        var category = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('#search_category_loader').css('display','block');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'ajaxreturn':131, 'searchCat': category},
            url: '<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/',
            //success:function(result){
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('#showSubCats').html(data); 
                jQuery('#search_subcategory').css('display','block');
                jQuery('#search_category_loader').css('display','none');
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please attache the JQuery

Comment: jquery is attached and I can alert these values.

Comment: I have edited my question, and have written jquery part of my question

Comment: did you faced errors on browser? all code running properly?

Comment: yes, code is running properly.

Comment: Why don't you build the full `select` code in your PHP response? Also, I don't understand how the `ajax.url` is even working with the value `<?php bloginfo('url') ?>`... See a [working plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15813761/1287812).

Comment: you managed to see on fiddler that the response from server is what you expected?

Comment: actually I am working on wordpress that's why I used <?php bloginfo('url') ?>. and php script is written in functions.php. let me try to build full select code. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801499/how-to-change-options-of-select-with-jquery) can help you,
for you'r convenience, try this:

```
$("#showSubCats").empty().append(data);
```