# How to use Ajax to update a second selectbox in jquery using the first selectbox's value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

First off, I'm using wordpress, and the goal is to choose a dropdown selectmenu item, structured in jquery, to choose a parent category. This choice then updates the second select menu with the sub-categories of the parent.

So far, I have this ajax:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $( "#categories" )
      .selectmenu({
        select: function getval() {
        var parent = $("#categories").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { parent : parent },
            type: "POST",
            success: success: function(response){
                $(".sub_cat").html(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error, possible missing file.");
            }
            }); //End of ajax
        alert(parent);
        } //End of getval

        }) //End selectMenu
      .selectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "overflow" );

    $( "#sub_cats" )
       .selectmenu()
       .selectmenu( "menuWidget" )
       .addClass( "overflow" );

     var categories = $('#categories');
     var subcats = $('#sub_cats');       
});
</script>
```

This is the HTML that will be populated:

```
<fieldset>
<div class=sub_cat>

</div>
</fieldset>
```

And This is ajax.php:

```
<?php
$parent = $_POST['parent'];
$subcats = get_categories("child_of=$parent");

$parent =   "<label for="sub_cats">Select a Sub-category</label>
            <select name="sub_cats" id="sub_cats">
            <option selected="selected">Pick a Sub-Category</option>" .
            foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
            "<option value=" echo $subcat->name ">" . echo $subcat->name . "</option>"
            } .
            "</select>"
?>
```

The menus come in as they should, the alerts come in and the parent category is always sent to the ajax when the choice is made. But the success alert is never touched and I have no idea what I'm supposed to put in the ajax.php file. My guess would be to use that file to get the sub-cats in php, and then send it in json format, but I don't know how.

Absolutely any help is appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a while.

I've tried the solutions from below but I never get any code or value back from ajax.php with any of their answers. Thats where it stops. I also don't know how to populate the next selectbox with the new item. Pretend Im a super ignorant programmer who doesn't know a thing about these structures and explain from that standpoint, that might help I hope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make output of a select list be dependant on parent list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748968/how-to-make-output-of-a-select-list-be-dependant-on-parent-list)

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax.php file ... do this ...

```
$parent = $_POST['parent'];

// Query the subcategories using parent ..

// then loop and create select box ...
```

Then the change the ajax success like below ... and fill the data to subcatogory div

```
success: function(response){
    $(".subcat-div").html(response);
}
```

Comment: Let me update my initial post with the new code, I feel like I'm close, I just may be missing some small syntax bit.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is in change event in your #categories 
this must send a request to server and response in html format refreshes #sub_cats

Let us see:

```
//in your js 

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#categories").change(function(){
        //here we get corrent selected id 
        //form categories in corrent selected option
        var id = $(this).val();

        //simple ajax request $.post
        $.post("ajax.php",{
            id:id           
        },function(data){
            $("#sub_cats").empty()
            $("#sub_cats").append(data)
        },"html")
    });
}

//
```

On ajax.php your return must be in Html

... your query above end fetching result:

```
while($sub = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value='".$sub['id']."'>".$sub['name']."</option>";
}
```

Check it out.

Comment: So am I putting the while looped items as they are, in to a variable, and then POSTing that in ajax.php?

Comment: All I get from this is what I had before.