# Multiple dropdown search for multiple custom taxonomies on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, drop-down-menu, custom-taxonomy

I've been trying every code I can find on the internet to achieve a multiple drop-down search with custom taxonomies on Wordpress 4.0. I have created the custom taxonomies.

I am building an education directory and want to achieve something like this:

Country (<--custom taxonomy)
- Select Country -
- USA (<-- term)
- United Kingdom
- ....

Qualification
- Select Qualification - 
- Bachelor
- Master
- ....

Major
- Select Qualification - 
- Business
- Science
- ....

[Submit Button]

For example, if someone searches and submit for "USA" "Bachelor" and "Science", it will display all post that are tagged in the terms.

If someone searches "USA" "Bachelor" and leave Major blank, it will display all post that are tagged in "USA" and "Bachelor" only.

I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make output of a select list be dependant on parent list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748968/how-to-make-output-of-a-select-list-be-dependant-on-parent-list)

Comment: Thanks but I need it for custom taxonomies as my category is used for my blog post.

Comment: Just set **`'taxonomy' => 'YOUR-TAXONOMY'`**

Comment: I don't seem to understand as I am very new to taxonomies. I would appreciate if you can guide me more. Thank you.

Comment: In that example there's only one place where you can set the above.