# Create a shortcode for a handmade plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I'm working on WordPress actually and created a plugin from scratch, fully working on admin page.
The plugin allow you to add country and languages related (USA->English|Sapnish for example)
I am using Class and constructor for the plugin's functions

Now I would like to created a select with country and depending on country another select with languages. I know how to create this in js/html but I can't find a way to get the data from the plugin.

I tried :
Create a function (in the plugin) who used plugin's other functions (see below)

```
public function getCountry()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "country_wmu";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name);
    if ($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
        echo '<p class="info-wmu error">Une erreur est survenue</p>';
    } else {
        return $results;
    }
}

public function getLang($id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "lang_wmu";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . ' WHERE _id_country = ' . $id);

    if ($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
        echo '<p class="info-wmu error">Une erreur est survenue</p>';
    } else {
        return $results;
    }
}

public function wmu_get_data($atts, $content=null)
{

    $country = $this->getCountry();

    foreach ($country as $key => $value) {
        $country_id = $value->id;
        $lang = $this->getLang($country_id);
        foreach ($lang as $key2 => $value2) {
            $country[$key]->lang = array(
                'name' => $value2->name,
                'url' => $value2->url
            );
        }

    }
    return $country;
}
```

and then add shortcode

```
add_shortcode('wmu_data', 'wmu_get_data');
```

and displaying the shortcode in the page, but shortcode displays as plain text

```
[wmu_data]
```

So I tried to do a function in my functions.php to do a do_shortcode, then add a shortcode to this function.

```
function test()
{
    $country = do_shortcode('[wmu_data]');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($country);
    echo '</pre>';
}

add_shortcode('test','test');
```

But nothing happens, blank page...

I really don't have many more ideas to do it...

**EDIT:**

I found out with the error code, Have to use

```
add_shortcode('wmu_data', array('WB_MultiLang_URL','wmu_data'));
```

to call it outside the function

thanks Larjos for pointing out the problem at his root :)

Comment: Are you calling `add_shortcode('wmu_data', 'wmu_get_data');` inside your plugin class?

Comment: Have you checked your error log? What errors do you find there from the time you have unsuccessfully loaded the page?

Comment: You need AJAX for this, I think this example should get you started: [How to make output of a select list be dependant on parent list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15813761/1287812)

Comment: I'll answer tomorrow, have to go, but thanks for helping ! See ya :)

Comment: @cabrerahector I 'm calling it outside my plugin classe

Comment: @LajosArpad I just checked It says "do_shortcode_tag it's called the wrong way"...

Comment: @brasofilo I dont get how ajax is helping in my problem haha ? :)

Comment: @Maël please add the stack trace to the question and let me know about it. Also, please add the way you call do_shortcode_tag and its definition. That should give us enough information to help you.

Comment: I edited my question I solved it but can't figure where to mark as Resolved, you was write telling me to check error log, begginner's mistake haha, thanks !